# $cordovaFileTransfer.download null error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, download, file-transfer

I'm trying to download a PNG file from my webserver with the next code:

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
    var url = "http://foo.bar/img/image.png";
    var filename = url.split("/").pop();
    var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'Pictures/' + filename;


    // This line print: "image.png"
    console.log(filename);

    // This line print: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/image.png"
    console.log(targetPath);

    $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, {}, true).then(function (result) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            console.log('Save file on '+targetPath+' success!');

    }, function (error) {
            console.log("Error");
            // This returns me the error.
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));

    }, function (progress) {
            console.log((progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100);

    });

}, false);
```

But I get always the next error:

`{"code":null,"source":null,"target":null,"http_status":null,"body" :null,"exception":null}`

Anybody know what's happening here?

---

**My enviroment information:**

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 1.2.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
Node Version: v4.2.2
```

---

**My device:**

```
Samsumg Galaxy S4 (android 5)
```

Comment: No, no errors.  Only one object with null properties (and just because I did a console.log() with stringify)

Comment: What other AJAX call? If you mean the rest of the program, it works well. I only can't make work this plugin

Comment: Android 5. Samsumg Galaxy S4

Comment: Sorry for the delay. My android target version is 20 and minsdkversion 16

Comment: I tried with 23. Doesnt work too :(

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: @MartaGom Check out this link for working sample app - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Comment: @Gandhi I will try this sample. Thanks 

Comment: @MartaGom welcome. Keep me posted.

Comment: @Homen I have  the android 5.1.1 platform installed

Comment: @Gandhi your sample works... But its a bit chaotic  jeje. Could you write a simple answer with $cordovaFileTransfer??

Comment: @MartaGom Unfortunately i dont have hands on experience on Ionic... But the core for this is the vanilla cordova file transfer

Comment: @Gandhi thank you very much. I will study this sample in more depth

Comment: @MartaGom sure.let me know if u hav any query. Worst case post ur project in github so that we can debug

Comment: I can't post all my proyect, but I already show the code  that does not work as well as all the enviroment and logs information..

Comment: I sure it would have given error in device console... Debug in device using chrome inspect devices option for more info

Comment: I get no errors.. I use `ionic run android --consolelogs --livereload` So I can see the logs inside my console. And there is no errors... I only get a object with null properties (as I say before)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120245/discussion-between-gandhi-and-martagom).